# Stomp selector condition

Tags: jms, selector, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm registering a web client via Stomp to an ActiveMQ messaging server. The clients have a username and register to a common topic by setting a selector.

```
var headers = {'selector': "to = '" + userName + "'"};
```

A client sends a message by setting a 'to' attribute in the header. Is it possible to also receive broadcast messages with a more complex selector? I'm looking for something like

```
var headers = {'selector': "to = '" + self.userName + "' OR *"};
```

to receive messages destined for all users.

Comment: I have the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72713805/php-stomp-selector-for-activemq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind the question. I found a solution. It's actually pretty much as I already guessed (I really should have tried it before posting). There's also a ActiveMQ document on that: http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html

The correct syntax is

```
var headers = {'selector': "to = '" + self.userName + "' OR '*'"};
```

Comment: Hi, orange,
I have the same issue, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72713805/php-stomp-selector-for-activemq