# PHP stomp selector for ActiveMQ

Tags: php, activemq-classic, message-queue, stomp

```
$topic  = '/topic/orders';
$selector = "orders IN ('1233', '345', '22222')";
$username = 'username'; $pass = 'pass';

$connection = new Connection($brokerUri);
$client = new Client($connection);
$client->setLogin($username, $pass);
$stomp = new StatefulStomp($client);
$stomp->subscribe($topic,$selector);
```

It will subscribe to the topic on ActiveMQ but the subscription will prefix with convert_string_expressions:

Please see attached image.

[image]

How can I fix this prefix?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `convert_string_expressions` is problematic?

Comment: On ActiveMQ, I saw other protocol like amqp not showing this convert_string_expressions text but stomp subscription does but works.

Comment: Other protocols like AMQP don't need the `convert_string_expressions:` prefix because they support typed properties whereas STOMP doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ "Classic" is hard-coded to prefix any selector used by a STOMP client with `convert_string_expressions:`. This was done via [AMQ-4146](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4146) almost 10 years ago now. The prefix is documented [here](https://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html) which states:

> The JMS spec states that a String property should not get converted to a numeric when used in a selector. So for example, if a message has the ‘age’ property set to String ‘21’ then the following selector should not match it: ‘age > 18’. Since ActiveMQ support STOMP client which can only send messages with string properties, that restriction is a bit limiting. If you want your JMS selectors to auto-convert String properties the the appropriate number type, just prefix the the selector with ‘convert_string_expressions:’. If you changed selector in the previous example to be ‘convert_string_expressions:age > 18’, then it would match the message.

To "fix" this you'd have to submit a PR to the ActiveMQ project which adds a new configuration parameter for the STOMP connector to make this behavior configurable. That said, there should be no reason to change this as it shouldn't be hurting anything.

Comment: Thank you, Justin,
message data will be a byte array of GZipped data on ActiveMQ, Do you know does stomp transport this data message ?

Comment: This question seems completely unrelated to your original query about `convert_string_expressions`. I think you should create a new question for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation of this. Can you please comment here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718198/stomp-byte-array-of-gzipped-data

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!