# Can ActiveMQ trasport byte array of GZipped data through STOMP?

Tags: php, activemq-classic, message-queue, stomp, amazon-mq

Producers Message data is a byte array of GZipped data on ActiveMQ. Does STOMP transport this data message to the consumers?

Comment: Are you have a specific problem transmitting this data through STOMP? If so, can you elaborate on what that problem is?

Comment: You need to describe the actual issue you're having, including error messages and relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect ActiveMQ to transport any byte array through STOMP no matter what that byte array represents.